# Which is the transposition of this code in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How should be written the following code in ES6?

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    pkg: require('./package.json')
};
```

I have thought to something like this:

```
export function register(server, options, next) {
  next();
}

export const register.attributes = {
  pkg: require('./package.json')
};
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: what's wrong with the way it is?  (if it ain't broke...)

Comment: eslint reveal my an error in register.attributes line

Comment: you need to tell lint you're using node.js in the config options, the error is just because `exports` is not a universal keyword.

Comment: and lint doesn't find code errors, it finds code fragments that look like they could be written a more clear or maintainable fashion.

Comment: Do you need `attributes` to be attached to the `register` function, or can you export it separately? `export const register.attributes =` doesn't make sense, you either need to assign to a property, or declare a variable, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export function register() {}` declares a function with the name `register` in the local scope. This is the variable that you need to use to create a property on it, just as you did use `exports.register` to refer to the function in your ES5 snippet. So use

```
export function register(server, options, next) {
  next();
}
register.attributes = {
  pkg: require('./package.json')
};
```

`const register.attributes = …` is a mix of a property assignment and a variable declaration, which cannot work.